# TypeOrm findOne throws 'Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters'

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

Hi I'm using NestJs with TypeOrm and currently connected to a MongoDB (but I want to be independent because most customers use MSSQL and Postgres databases).

Basically I want to store a key/value pair to the database. Both are of type `String`. This is the mapping entity holding the pair

```
@Entity()
export class Mapping extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  key: string;

  @Column()
  value: string;
}
```

The repository is currently empty

```
@EntityRepository(Mapping)
export class MappingsRepository extends Repository<Mapping> {}
```

In my service file I try to find a value by its key

```
  public async getValueByKey(key: string): Promise<string> {
    const mapping: Mapping = await this.mappingsRepository.findOne(key);

    if (!mapping) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Key ${key} does not exist`);
    }

    return mapping.value;
  }
```

Unfortunately the `findOne` function always throws this error when passing in a key

> Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of
>   24 hex characters

How can I fix this so that I can pass in any keys of type `String`? The parameter `key` is defined, I tried it with dummy values like `f` or `ffsdagsdgfdg`

Comment: What is the value of `key`? Make sure it's defined.

Comment: It is defined. I tested it with random strings. So the parameter itself comes with a random string which is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

`await this.mappingsRepository.findOne({key});`

My guess it that `typeorm` doesn't understand primary key other than `id`

Answer (score 0):

`findOne` for mongo means it will search document by property `_id` and not your `key`
because, mongo, by default, always add this `_id` as unique validator for each document
so, you should provide a query to that method like it is defined in `itssajan` answer

but i think your use case of TypeORM is not the best, because it is made to work with SQL dbs, and not NoSQL dbs